# How to find and replace "=" in a text file with "," using Windows batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

My text file "new1.txt" contains the following:

1:Q4659A.LDS:4:LNAM=90210;90210
2:Q4159A.LDS:4:LNAM=90232;90210

2. I have tried to use delayed expansion logic but always end with error as

> ==,%" was unexpected at this time.

Code:

```
 set "search=="
 set "replace=,"
 echo %search%
 echo %replace%
 set "textfile=new1.txt"
 set "new1file=new2.txt"
 (for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
    set "line=%%i"
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!line!
   endlocal
))>"%new1file%"
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the number of elements to replace in each line (1 in your sample), then this can solve the problem

```
(for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=%search%" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
    echo(%%i%replace%%%j
))>"%new1file%"
```

Use the equal sign as a delimiter, get the splitted tokens and output them with the desired separator

Answer (score 1):

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
type new1.txt |repl "=" "," >new2.txt
```